# How to add a text box + combo box

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to coding and wondering is there any way to get these numbers and divide them by each other

The first number (250) is from a JTextField and the second number (50) is from a JComboBox.
         [Image of what im trying to say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Roje6.png)
e.g temp = 250 / 50 = 5

then to print it out Sopln("" + temp);

not sure if that makes sense but thats the best i can describe it

Comment: Don't add images of text! Please [edit] to add the text itself. Then use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them inside a `String` variable and then use them however you like.

For example

```
String a = t1.getText();
String b = c1.getSelectedItem();
```

Here you should use `substring(int beginIndex)` for remove the `%` in your `b String`.

> This method has two variants and returns a new string that is a substring of this string.

```
String b_edit = b.substring(0, 2); // Now your b_edit = 50
```

At this point we have `a = 250` and `b_edit = 50`

Now if you try to `a + b_edit` the result will be `25050`. Thats because both variables are strings.

To overcome this problem, you can use `parseInt()`.

> This method is used to get the primitive data type of a certain String. parseXxx() is a static method and can have one argument or two.

```
int int_a = Integer.parseInt(a);
int int_b = Integer.parseInt(b_edit);

int temp = int_a + int_b;
```

If you `print` your `temp` variable , the result will be `300`.

```
System.out.println(temp);
```

Comment: Thanks :D this helps a lot

Comment: I added some new information, if the answer is exhaustive, check it as the answer, so other people can use it as well.

Comment: parseInt is in red and slice is in red unsure why its like that.  the only thing i can do for parseInt is private Object parseInt(Object b_edit) {
 
  return c1.getSelectedItem();
 }  Not sure if thats ok?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Are you sure it's Javascript?

Comment: yes, i think so, Again im new so not sure sorry, I use Eclipse IDE to code in

Comment: its Java not Javascript sorry for that :/

Comment: Edited with Java command :)

Comment: i got it to work after changing an Error "Type Mismatched cannot change object into string" this is the code i currently have --> https://imgur.com/a/mAhe5Bo  But ive run into another minor problem where if my combo box is set to 100 it adds it as a 10 is that to do with ( String b_edit = ((String) b).substring(0, 2); ) line? and is there any easy way to fix this or should i just change it to 99

Comment: I noticed that you understood that the variables must be initialized by specifying their type, therefore, since `getselectitem()` is a `function`, it must be initialized as an `Object`. As for the second small problem, `substring(0,2)` take from the first to second index, but 100% got 4 index, so you should use `substring(0,3)`

Comment: thanks that's all the problems i had :D